# Map of functions in Swift

Tags: swift

Is it possible to have a map of `String:Function` in Swift?

Something like this (which is not working):

```
let map = [
    "action": func() { print("action!") },
    "error": func() {print("error!") }
]
```

What are other design patterns I can follow to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either do this by putting closures in the Dictionary

```
let map = [
    "action": {() in print("action!") },
    "error":  {() in print("error!") }
]
```

or by creating the functions outside the dictionary and giving them names, then passing those names into the Dictionary

```
func action() {
    print("action!")
}

func error() {
    print("error!")
}

let map = [
    "action": action,
    "error": error
]
```

It looks like what you want is an unnamed, anonymous function (aka closure) which is what the first solution gives you. The `func` keyword can only be used to create named functions.

Comment: [Docs on closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)